# webdav support for maven

Tags: java, maven, webdav

How to perform file upload, or file deletion, from webdav resources using maven? Preferably without ant tasks.
I need that to upload directories to remote locations, where the directory is not a maven site.
The maven wagon plugin seems not to support directory deletion, and that would be quite useful in order not to leave things behind when uploading

Comment: For what purposes are the webdav resources needed? during the build?

Comment: during deployment. mainly things like deploying p2 repositories, but possibly other directories in the future.

Comment: is your webdav server defined in pom.xml or settings.xml ? If so, just try using url with ftp schema as in `ftp://your.server/webdav/path`

Comment: well, I would prefer it was, but it doesn't need to be. pom.xml has no way of defining non site, non artifact non plugin repositories, so I believe that I wouldn't be able to define anything in pom.xml for it.

Comment: don't you need to authenticate to webdav server in order to upload?

Comment: yes, but the plugin/whatever that performs the upload may have another source of username and password than the server tag in settings.xml, especially in case no such plugin exists and I would need ant tasks that do not support that at all

Comment: If you need to have p2 repositories is to use Nexus OSS version 2.X and there you simply deploy P2 repositories into without any hassle about webdav ...

Comment: accessibility constraints. I am blind, and nexus has accessibility bugs. I am using artifactory oss.

Comment: I checked all the choices I had, including nexus3 and packagedrone, know nexus2 a little bit. I assume that artifactory is the best option I have, especially that packagedrone does not work for me at all, nexus2 I treat as outdated, and both nexus versions have accessibility problems. You can safely assume I have no choice except to manually manage p2 repositories, and that can be done only through webdav access, as direct archive content access and automatic archive extraction on upload are both only available in artifactory pro version.

Comment: Not sure if nexus2 supports p2 in oss version, I realize nexus3 currently does not support them...